Contrapositive proof of language irregularity via pumping lemma for a specific language
Closed. This question is not about programming or software development. It is not currently accepting answers.
This question does not appear to be about a specific programming problem, a software algorithm, or software tools primarily used by programmers. You can edit the question so it's on-topic or see if it can be answered on another Stack Exchange site, but be sure to read the on-topic page for a site before posting there.
Closed 26 mins ago.
Could anyone help me find such string for a language that by definition contains amount of "100" substrings that does not exceed amount of "011" substrings. What I have concluded so far is that it is impossible to do that because no matter what the string is, if we choose the p (pumping length) = 1, then we can omit x prefix (when the word is divided into part xyz) and have the first char (y) pumped as many times as we want. The resulting string will always still be in the initial language because the first symbol of either string is not repeating, it is the second one that does. If it was vice versa that it would be a different story.
FYI: the alphabet consits of 0s and 1s and the words can be constructed from any sequences of 0s and 1s as long as the initial condition holds.

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

You do not choose $p$ when refuting the pumping lemma.
